# Why won't my oven turn on?

Tags: oven

My GE Gas Range JGB281DER3BB is not turning on.
This is what I've done troubleshooting.

1. The igniter glows and draws the correct power. I even detached it and attached it to another oven and it worked in the other oven.
2. I've checked the gas safety valve for continuity and its good.
3. The gas regulator switch was checked and it is on.
4. The broiler works fine

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be wrong with this oven?
Can the burner itself be no good?
Thanx in advance.
Itz

Comment: No gas getting though, clogged jets/valve.  Flame sensor is bad, not turning on gas.  Bad control circuit.

Comment: When you say "doesn't turn on", I presume you mean that the burners don't ignite, right? Have you confirmed that you're getting gas flow through the burner (is that what #3 means)?

Comment: Yes, I meant that the burner doesn't ignite and yes, that is what by #3

Comment: But you can hear gas coming out of the burner?  If you use a match/grill lighter, does it ignite?